# activate a worksheet with a string

Tags: string, vba, variables

Having some problems here... I want my worksheet to be ("In shipping") or ("In pack")
so worksheet("In variable") I am using button captions to give my input
Here is what I have

```
    Dim department1 As String
    department1 = Area.Caption
    Dim department2 As String
    department2 = toarea.Caption
    Dim ws1 As String
    ws1 = Chr(34) & "In " & department1 & Chr(34)
    Dim ws2 As String
    ws2 = Chr(34) & "In " & department2 & Chr(34)

    MsgBox Chr(34) & "In " & department2 & Chr(34)

    Dim slot1 As String
    slot1 = Worksheets(ws1).Range("I1")
    Dim slot2 As String
    slot2 = Worksheets(ws2).Range("I1")
```

But it is failing on SLOT1 and SLOT2 does not see Worksheets(ws1).Range("I1") as in range

Comment: is your sheet name `""In Shipping""` or `In Shipping` or `"In Shipping"`?

Answer (score 0):

I assume what you're trying to reproduce is:

`Worksheets("In shipping")` using a variable instead of the specific string.

To accomplish that, you need not to put any extra `"`.

For example, to reproduce accurately, try the following :

```
department1 = "shipping" 'eventually replace with Area.Caption
ws1 = "In " & department1
slot1 = Worksheets(ws1).Range("I1")
```